# Micro SD card overheats Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: pi-2, sd-card

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, and I plugged in the charger - it was fine. I plugged in the HDMI - still fine. I plugged in the micro SD card (64GB) and the Pi immediately got super hot and when I touched it, it burned my hand. I retried by plugging things in in a different order, and the problem was proven to occur when the micro SD card was in. I even tried different chargers, nothing different happened. Should I get a new SD card, do I need a new PI?

Comment: Have you tried with other SD cards? Or reformatting the card?

Comment: What exactly is getting hot? How hot is hot? I doubt it is the SD card, but rather the processor and hence the board id dying or already dead.

Comment: Wait, you plugged in the sd card **after** plugging in the power? I'm not certain that's a safe thing to do with the RPi...

Comment: I've done it both ways - before and after

Comment: @Mashpoe Always plug in the SD card before power. Anyways, have you tried it on another device? Phone/PC/camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a new SD card. In the worst case, [prepare yourself to get a new Pi.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/43049/24224)

Immediate heat on any component other than a stove or a toaster is not a good sign at all especially in electronics. In a circuit, it usually denotes something is causing a short circuit. In an IC component (like your SD card or the Pi's CPU), it's usually a sign of physical damage to a component, even if it's not visible.

If your micro SD card still works, set it aside and get another micro SD you're okay with breaking (no important data and such). If the Pi still heats up, it's a good idea to replace it (no, you can't fix it).

### Always plug in the power last!

Update: Also check your card if it's compatible using this list: http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards

Comment: I figured it out, you must use a high-capacity sd card (HC). I bought a new one from best buy. I am accepting your answer, but it would be nice if you edited your answer to say it needs to be a high-capacity sd card. thanks!

Comment: @Mashpoe how big was the card you were using? What do you consider high capacity?

Comment: @Mashpoe No, it doesn't need to be HC (high capacity). It can even be XC. Most cards are simply labeled "HC" these days. Non-HC and non-XC cards will also work.

Comment: @Mashpoe Your old card is probably not supported then. Take a look at this list: http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards